# Is there a limit to the number of broadcast variables you have in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I know there is a memory limit for broadcast variables in Spark. I also know this can be changed with memory-driver configurations. I would like to know if there is a limit on how many variables you can broadcast?

My problem is that I have five variables that I use for look ups. I am initializing them prior to a closure(flatmap) and passing the value into the flatmap. However there is one broadcast that is empty and size of zero after passing it through the closure. It is not empty before. One variable is an Java ArrayList, Two are Java Hashmaps, One is a service, and the last is a SetMultimap(com.google.common.collect). All but the SetMultiMap are working and retaining there sizes and data. The SetMultimap contains only 98 entries. All broadcast have a bytes size of 8,264 (Using the Spark Size Estimator), so not very large for all to be broadcasted. I thought that odd that all the broadcast were the same but maybe there is some standard sizes for broadcast. Inside the closure when I look at the sizes, all but the SetMultimap are the same size as they were prior to broadcasting.

Example:

```
    Initialization of HashMultimap;

    var idMap: SetMultimap[String, String] = _
    ....
    #Inside method that returns the filled HashMultimap
    idMap = HashMultimap.create()


    //Sizes prior to broadcast
    Array (.size) = 1208
    HashMultiMap (.size) = 98
    HashMapOne (.size) = 87
    HashMapTwo (.size) = 85
    service is not null


    //Broadcasting to use later
    val broadcastArray = context.broadcast(Array) # SizeEstimator 8264 bytes
    val broadcastMultiMap = context.broadcast(HashMultiMap) # SizeEstimator 8264 bytes
    val broadcastHashMapOne = context.broadcast(HashMapOne) # SizeEstimator 8264 bytes
    val broadcastHashMapTwo = context.broadcast(HashMapTwo) # SizeEstimator 8264 bytes
    var broadcastService = context.broadcast(ExampleService.getService) # SizeEstimator 8264 bytes


    sampleRDD.flatMap { case (_, value) => sampleFunc(value, broadcastArray.value, broadcastHashMultiMap.value, broadcastHashMapOne.value,  broadcastService.value, broadcastHashMapTwo.value)


   def sampleFunc(<parms>){

   //Sizes inside closure
    Array (.size) = 1208
    HashMultiMap (.size) = 0/Empty
    HashMapOne (.size) = 87
    HashMapTwo (.size) = 85
    service is not null
   }
```

I have serialized the class with Kryo and that was not an issue.

I would think spark would throw an error in that case. Can anyone enlighten me on why the HashMultiMap is empty in the executors when all of the other broadcast work as expected when I issue .value? As well as a possible solution to this where I can keep the HashMultiMap?

UPDATE: When I do not broadcast it works fine, I will do that for now until an answer is posted.

Spark Version: 1.6.2 , Scala Version: 2.11

Comment: Can you please include some sample code that shows the issue?

Comment: Added some example code